# Unexpected network error in VB script

Tags: windows

I need a help.I am getting occasional ‘Unexpected network error’ when the
VB scripts try to write a log files reside in NAS.

It happens when the previous steps runs longer and they try to write inside a file in NAS after an hour or so.

Comment: Sounds like the storage system has a timeout.